# How to make a Chat room with react and firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo, chat

I'm working with Expo, React, Firebase and Material UI and I made a Social media App now I'm trying to make a Chat room in my app. I found some interesting articles, tutorials and documentations and got this code to work.

Chat.js

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
    import { db, auth } from '../firebase'
    import SendMessages from './SendMessages'
    
        function Chat() {
            const scroll = useRef()
            const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
            useEffect(() => {
                db.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt').limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
                })
            }, [])
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="msgs">
                        {messages.map(({ id, text, photoURL, uid }) => (
                            <div>
                                <div key={id} className={`msg ${uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received'}`}>
                                    <img src={photoURL} alt="" />
                                    <p>{text}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <SendMessages scroll={scroll} />
                    <div ref={scroll}></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        
        export default Chat
```

SendMessages.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { db, auth } from '../firebase'
import SendMessages from './SendMessages'

function Chat() {
    const scroll = useRef()
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt').limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="msgs">
                {messages.map(({ id, text, photoURL, uid }) => (
                    <div>
                        <div key={id} className={`msg ${uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received'}`}>
                            <img src={photoURL} alt="" />
                            <p>{text}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <SendMessages scroll={scroll} />
            <div ref={scroll}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Now I can write messages from my profile and the Firebase DB is also working.

But now I'm wondering how do I make it possible for all users to write each other?
I would like to make it somehow like the Instagram chat room where you click on the chat button you see the other users u click them u write them.

I hope you know what I mean haha :)

Comment: Hey yes your answer helped a lot. I was sure I clicked the checkmark but obviously I was wrong. Sorry and thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to model is, is to make each chat room be its own document, and then store the messages for that chat room in a subcollection under it.

So in a data structure that would look like:

```
ChatRooms (collection)
  ChatRoom1 (document)
    Messages (collection)
      ...
  ChatRoom2 (document)
    Messages (collection)
      ...
```

So now you have two chat rooms, each with its own subcollection of messages. In the chat room document you'll typically store more global information about that chat room, such as the users that are part of that room, its name, and for example the text and timestamp of the most recent message to the room.

There are many more ways to model this though, so I recommend starting with this (or any model you think is reasonable) and then adapting it as you expand your use-case.